# Bitcoind lose the latest blocks when synchronize

Tags: bitcoind

I've the latest version of Bitcoin-qt (bitcoin.org 0.15.1). My problem is I lose info about latest blocks with delay about 3-5 minutes. When my GUI or bitcoind started sometimes for a short time I get this warning in debug.log:

> 2017-12-26 19:42:52 Timeout downloading block
>   000000000000000000594fca8fc2e2e6f7baff5ac96a10d94f33ae3b0f4e1971 from
>   peer=12, disconnecting

After that I lose latest new blocks for a while, and the easier way is restart bitcoind.

Is it could be because of that my ports is not forwarding and I have only 8 connections? What means this warning, I can't google it?

Comment: What do you mean lose info? What info? Did you have this information at any other time, or did you just never have it? The warning is a harmless message telling you that one of your peers is too slow at giving you a block, so the client will ask the block from someone else.

Comment: @PieterWuille Thanks for answering! I mean info about the latest blocks in the blockchain. I usually have a delay (3-5 min.) compared to btc.com or blockexplorer.com. When I try mining solo (jut for fun) I can't work on actual blocks - my Longpool work on outdated blocks for this reason. If I'm mining in a pool, stratum get actual blocks immediatly.

Comment: Sure if you just start up your client needs to synchronize with the network. It may take a few minute to learn and validate the most recent blocks. What do you expect?

Comment: @Pieter Wuille Yes, I know, but often I can't get actual blocks after my client synchronized 100%!
Debug.log show me "progress = 1.000000" but on the next step when new blocks assepted by the network already, my client is silent for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I didn't configure nodes settings and use unhealthy default nodes. When I specified "addnode=closestnodesIP" my problem was solved.